# How we get the previous data of fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application Main_Activity contain  four fragments. In one fragment (called mobile_fragment) whenever i click the button in fragment  it will move to another activity, in that i need to get the one value and need to send that data to that fragment(mobile_fragment).

what i done is:
 whenever i click the button in fragment i moved to activity and get  the value and that value sent to main_Activity, after that in mobile fragment i accessed that variable (static declaration of variable in main_activity).

Now my problem is after getting the value in mobile_fragment, i already entered values in  remaining edit text widgets are cleared (no text). how i get previously entered values?
 please any one help me.

```
fragment


    public class Mobile_Fragment extends Fragment {
       @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (container == null) {
                return null;
            }
      browseplans.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BrowsePlans_Activity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
       }}


BrowseplansActivty:

  Intent intent=new Intent(BrowsePlans_Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra("Amount",amount);
               startActivity(intent);

Main_Activity:

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

        public static String TAG = "Main First Frag";




        public static String contact_number, prepaid_amt;

        Fragment fragment;
        FragmentManager frgManager;
        FragmentTransaction ft;

        Bundle b = new Bundle();



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            initUI();
            bindEvents();// now this is my changed one
            Intent in=getIntent();
            prepaid_amt=in.getStringExtra("Amount");
            Log.v("TAG+AMOUNT",""+prepaid_amt);
    }
    }
```

Comment: please any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from your fragment to the Activity you are starting, pass it through [Intent Extras](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

To return data from the Activity back to the fragment, call `setResult` with a result code and an intent that, again, holds data set with extras. Retrieve that data in the `onActivityResult` override of your fragment.

To save information in a fragment when it is detached and then re-attached, use the override [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and then extract data from that state in `onCreate` and/or `onCreateView` overrides.

Comment: could you please provide any links?  with the help of intents i sent data from activty to Main_activity? i already used oncreate .

Comment: Here is the link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html . Also, from my practice, it's very bad design to use a static variable for such a purpose in Android, it leads to code which you can't understand absolutely.

Comment: i am new to android. i dnt have much knowledge on parsing data...with fragments...could you please tell me how to send data